# Subscribing to button click in Reactive Extensions and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, system.reactive

I have a WPF application using Reactive Extensions and I am trying to subscribe to button clicks.

```
 var click = Observable.FromEvent<RoutedEventHandler,RoutedEventArgs>(h => btn.Click += h,h=> btn.Click -= h);
  click.Window(n).Subscribe(window =>
  {

  });
```

this code seems ok according to some tutorial I found but it fails with

```
Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type.
```

I also found that something like this should work

var click = Observable.FromEvent(btn, "Click");

but this does not get compiled.

Comment: Have you considered using MVVM and binding your button to a `Command`? (and then using Rx to subscribe to this `Command`'s execution?)

Comment: Try using RxUI to bridge the gap to rx. This sort of coding is against best practice, and will quickly lead to unmaintainable code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `FromEvent` if you are going to use `RoutedEventHandler,RoutedEventArgs` you have to use `FromEventPattern<RoutedEventHandler,RoutedEventArgs>` to make it work. `FromEvent` is for non-standard .NET events.

```
var click = Observable.FromEventPattern<RoutedEventHandler,RoutedEventArgs>(h => btn.Click += h,h=> btn.Click -= h);
  click.Window(n).Subscribe(window =>
  {

  });
```